# How i can upload an image with CreateView on my post?

Tags: python, django, post, file-upload, image-uploading

I have had some problems, I can upload text like the field 'text' and the field 'video' in which I place a URLField, the problem is that from the administration panel I can upload the image without any problem. But at the time of doing it by CreateView from a view I am not possible.

I was told to add the tag (enctype = "multipart / form-data") to the form and it works, but instead of uploading it to /media/posts/image.jpg it attempts to upload it to (/ media / image .jpg) and the end of it all is that it does not upload the image.

I really just want to upload the images to my posts as you can see here https://plxapp.herokuapp.com/ and later do so with the avatar and the header of the UserProfile.

If they have any procedure or validation that should be done, they can tell me here.

I leave my code:

Template:

```
        <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ form.subject.id_text }}">Text</label>
                {{ form.text }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ form.subject.id_image }}">Image</label>
                {{ form.image }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ form.subject.video }}">Video</label>
                {{ form.video }}
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Publish <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </form>
```

views.py:

```
class PostCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('timeline')
    template_name = 'posts/post_new.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.date_created = timezone.now()
        obj.save()
        return redirect('timeline')
```

forms.py:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'What are you thinking?', 'maxlength': '200', 'rows': '3'})
)
    image = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), required=False
)
    video = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.URLInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Youtube, Twitch.tv, Vimeo urls.', 'aria-describedby': 'srnm'}), required=False
)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('text', 'image', 'video')
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts', blank=True)
    video = models.URLField(blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-date_created"]

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} (@{}) : {}".format(self.user.first_name,self.user.last_name, self.user.username,self.text)
```

Github (source):
https://github.com/cotizcesar/plaxedpy

Comment: why do you declare in your modelform again the fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a file field to your form you use the `FileField` from the `forms` module like `image = forms.FileField()`

If you want to modify the widgets of your form fields inside the form, just add the `widgets` property to the Meta class. Like this:

```
class PostForm(Form):
    image = FileField()
    class Meta:
        fields = ('title', 'text')
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'what': 'ever'}),
             }
```